# REST api desing. Retrieving and saving child records

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I am designing a rest api and I have some doubts about exposing and consuming children from relation.
Assuming I have an entity A with a one to many relation to entity B (so A can have some Bs attached) and I design an endpoint to create entity A and DTO for entity A includes a list for entity B and user provides a valid one, should it be saved too?

Example:
Doing a **post** to some endpoint e.g. /api/v1/As

```
{
    entityAfield1: someValue,
    entityAfield2: someOtherValue
    Bs: [
        {
            HERE a valid B payload
        }
    ]
}
```

should I also save B and create a relation between A and B? What if B also have some children? Should it be saved too?
Or should I just save A and create an endpoint like

```
/api/v1/As/{Aid}/Bs/{Bid}
```

to create a relation?
And same question about getting data. Should get always retrieve all children? I couldn't find a clear answer to this on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be solved by means of returning the IDs of Bs. This way, a user of service will decide whether or not to retrieve the actual data of related resources.

To interact with those an endpoint like this

```
/api/v1/Bs/{Bid}
```

can be used, as well as a more verbose one

```
/api/v1/As/{Aid}/Bs/{Bid}
```

however, the too nested endpoints, like

```
/api/v1/As/{Aid}/Bs/{Bid}/Cs/{Cid}/Ds/{Did}
```

should be avoided and most likely indicate a design flaw.

For a tree structure or many to many relations in general, an intermediate resource that represents a linkage should be exposed. There is [a good example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) of a REST API implementation by Google, its "Children" section would be especially helpful for such case.